# Value of type 'Any' has no member 'removeFromSuperview'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Q.1 Why does 'Any' has no member 'removeFromSuperview'?

Q.2 Why does it say cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject' or use 'as!' to force downcast to a more specific type to access members?

```
    var allImgViews = [Any]()
    viewDidLoad(){
     // sample code
     for v in 0..<4 {
      myImageView.image = UIImage(named: something)
      allImgViews.append(myImageView)
     }
      allImgViews[0].removeFromSuperview()
     }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Because `Any` literally means `any`. What's to stop you from putting the `Int` value 0 in that array, and then trying tot call `removeFromSuperView` on it? How should the program decide what to do?

Comment: Where does `myImageView` come from?

Comment: myImageView is created programmatically; something similar to let  myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(), y: CGFloat(192), width: CGFloat(98), height: CGFloat(94)))

Comment: @Amrit Instead of `var allImgViews = [Any]()` you just use `var allImgViews = [UIImageView]()`. so `removeFromSuperview()` will come to know that `allImgViews` is an array of `UIImageView` and it will allow you to use that method.

Comment: @Amrit No need for the `CGFloat` constructors. `CGRect` always stores its members as `CGFloat`.

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"...something similar to let myImageView =..."*? Seriously, you make it sound like it's, well, "close, but not really".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because `Any` means literally ***ANY*** data type. There's nothing that requires an `Any` typed value to have to be able to be a view that's capable of being added or removed from a view. `Int` can be an `Any`, `String` can be an `Any`. What would you expect something like this to do?

   ```
   let any: Any = 123
   any.removeFromSuperView() // What should this call do??? o.0'
   ```
2. Because you only know the members of a value by the type that you know the value has. That's what a type is: it's a categorization of values by what operations you can perform on them.

   In a type-safe language like Swift, you can't perform any operation unless your sure the value your doing it to supports that operation. And you gain that certainty when you know the values exact type, because then you can check to see whether that type supports the operation or member you're trying to use.

There's no reason to be using `Any` here, in the first place. Here's how to write this with nice, specific types:

```
var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

func viewDidLoad() {
    for v in 0..<4 {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 192, width: 98, height: 94))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: something)
        imageViews.append(imageView)
    }

    imageView[0].removeFromSuperview()
}
```

If `imageViews` has no values before the `append` calls in `viewDidLoad`, this code can be better written as:

```
let imageViews = [UIImageView]()

func viewDidLoad() {
    imageViews = (0..<4).map { v in
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 192, width: 98, height: 94))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: something)
        return imageView
    }

    imageView[0].removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: @Alexander we need to check imageViewcount before accessing zero'th  index

Comment: @Jack No we don't, we just added 4 items to it. We know it's not empty

Comment: @Jack Even if you wanted to avoid this theoretically unsafe operation, `array.count > 0` is not the right way to do it. `!array.isEmpty` would be better, but best of all would be to use `array.first`, and safely unwrap the optional